# How to place search query in the URL?

Tags: string, url, search

With a lot of search engines, you can find the string you are searching in the URL.

However, http://drugcompare.destinationrx.com/Home.aspx does not let me do this. When I search something, the resulting URL is http://drugcompare.destinationrx.com/DrugCompare.aspx no matter what.

Is there any way I can find out whether I can search the website by adding something to the end of the URL, like "?query=searchstring" instead of using the form provided on the page? Basically I need a unique URL.

Comment: Does http://drugcompare.destinationrx.com/Home.aspx and  http://drugcompare.destinationrx.com/DrugCompare.aspx are your websites?? If not then how do you expect you can change their functionalities

Answer (score 0, accepted):

that website you pointed at uses POST to send data for its search query which means you wont be able to see or append it on the URL bar. The reason for that is either for security or the search query it generates is a complex object or too long and does not fit in a url. websites such as search engines uses GET, with that you can append your search query in the url by following the syntax it generates.